# SQL - Inserting loop based on select rows

Tags: sql-server

I have thousands of rows in a sql server table which have a `START` row, I need to update the table and `INSERT` an `END` row for each of them.

```
 select  distinct transaction_id from transactions t1
      where
        this_status_id = 2 and that_type_id = 1
              and not exists
              (
              select  *
              from    transactions t2
              where   t2.transaction_id = t1.transaction_id
                      and t2.this_status_id in (1,3,4)
                      and t2.that_type_id = 1
              )
```

This select returns a list of IDs (not the primary key)
I need to loop through each of the ids from the above select, and INSERT into the same table like:

```
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES (@transaction_id, "finished", 1, 2, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Why reinsert the same ID's? Why don't you perform an UPDATE?

Comment: Why Loop? `INSERT into transactions SELECT distinct transaction_ID, 'finished',1,2,getdate() FROM transactions`  from [MSFT (Insert into select...syntax](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189872(v=sql.105).aspx).   Loops are slow... set based processing in a RDBMS is so much more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why loop when you could just:

```
insert into transactions
select distinct transaction_id, 'finished', 1, 2, getdate()
from transactions
where this_status_id = 2 
  and that_type_id = 1
  and not exists (
    select  1
    from  transactions t2
    where t2.transaction_id = t1.transaction_id
      and t2.this_status_id in (1,3,4)
      and t2.that_type_id = 1
  );
```

---

Using a temporary table:

```
select distinct transaction_id 
into #TempTable
from transactions t1
where this_status_id = 2 
  and that_type_id = 1
  and not exists (
    select  1
    from  transactions t2
    where t2.transaction_id = t1.transaction_id
      and t2.this_status_id in (1,3,4)
      and t2.that_type_id = 1
  );

insert into transactions
distinct transaction_id, 'finished', 1, 2, getdate()
from #TempTable;
```

Comment: my select distinct is a crazy long select with `not exists` etc does that matter since it just brings back a long list of IDs>?  I've update my question to show the large SELECT to get the ids

Comment: @user3437721 It shouldn't. If you want to dump it into a temporary table first that would be fine as well.